# enable/disable checkbox by its resident cell location

Tags: forms, vba, checkbox, disabled-control

I want to disable/enable a checkbox in an excel sheet using vba based on the value/conditon of another checkbox. I cannot use the checkbox name, I want to use it's cell location in reference to the cell location of the checkbox that is enabling/disabling it. something like this:

```
Sub Software2()

    Dim myRange As Range

    Set myRange = Range(ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller).TopLeftCell.Address)

    If ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller).ControlFormat.Value = 1 Then

        myRange.Interior.ColorIndex = 35
        myRange.Offset(0, 1).Interior.ColorIndex = 35
        myRange.Offset(0, 2).Interior.ColorIndex = 35
        myRange.Offset(1, 1).Interior.ColorIndex = 44
        myRange.Offset(1, 2).Interior.ColorIndex = 44
        myRange.Offset(2, 1).Interior.ColorIndex = 44
        myRange.Offset(2, 2).Interior.ColorIndex = 44
    Else

        myRange.Interior.ColorIndex = 44
        myRange.Offset(0, 1).Interior.ColorIndex = 44
        myRange.Offset(0, 2).Interior.ColorIndex = 44
        myRange.Offset(1, 1).Interior.ColorIndex = 0
        myRange.Offset(1, 2).Interior.ColorIndex = 0
        myRange.Offset(2, 1).Interior.ColorIndex = 0
        myRange.Offset(2, 2).Interior.ColorIndex = 0
        'ActiveSheet.Shapes(location of other checkbox).ControlFormat.Enabled = 0
        'ActiveSheet.Shapes(location of other checkbox).ControlFormat.Enabled = 0

    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Shapes have a `TopLeftCell` property which returns (unsurprisingly) the cell under their top left corner

Comment: Yes, I am using that property from the main checkbox. I will edit my question to include the code I have so far.

Comment: You will need to loop over the sheets shapes and look for the one whose toleftcell value matches the cell you're interested in.  You could write a function to do that to make it tidier.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a demo of how to find a control by its position relative to a range.

`TopLeftCell` is a bit finicky since the control might drift a bit to the top and/or left and so not get found.  Using relative Top/Left position is a bit more robust.

You could even combine the two - depends on the relative size of the cell and the control.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Tester()

    Dim cb

    Set cb = GetControlFromRange(Range("B6"))
    If Not cb Is Nothing Then
        Debug.Print cb.Name
        'toggle enabled
        With cb.ControlFormat
            .Enabled = Not .Enabled
        End With
    End If


End Sub



Function GetControlFromRange(rng As Range) As Object
    Const POS_DELTA_MAX As Long = 10
    Dim c As Object, s As Shape
    For Each s In rng.Parent.Shapes
        If s.Type = msoFormControl Then

            'using TopLeftCell
'            If Not Application.Intersect(s.TopLeftCell, rng) Is Nothing Then
'                Set c = s
'                Exit For
'            End If

            'using position
            If Abs(s.Top - rng.Top) < POS_DELTA_MAX And _
               Abs(s.Left - rng.Left) < POS_DELTA_MAX Then
                Set c = s
                Exit For
            End If
        End If
    Next s
    Set GetControlFromRange = c
End Function
```